# mysql trigger that deletes a specific column record after it is updated

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

```
create table instructor (
ID char(5),
password varchar(256),
token varchar(256) null,
name varchar(20) not null,
dept_name varchar(20),
salary numeric(8,2));
```

example of records

```
id  password      token            name      dept_name          salary    
1   safakndanda   null             denis     cooking            50000    
2   adghbjksdaj   null             victor    cleaning           60000    
3   ahdagsdgda    gads5a7sd6as7d   peter     management         120000     
4   afsfgfdds     null             judy      management         300000
```

say token on id 3 was just updated  i want to write trigger that  will delete the data on recorded on token column for id=3  after 3 hours

Comment: Trigger must create event which is fired at NOW() + INTERVAL 3 HOUR and which will alter or delete the record in interest.

Comment: 'i want to write trigger' - you can't. You cannot action a table in a trigger which fired the trigger. As others have suggested you need an EVENT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need additional column for save token updated time, with will be updated on each token update by code or by MySQL trigger.

Next, you should to use [Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html) for this.

```
CREATE EVENT ExpireTokens
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR DO
BEGIN
    UPDATE instructor 
    SET 
        token = NULL 
    WHERE 
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, token_updated_at, NOW()) > 3 AND
        token IS NOT NULL
END;
```